# Deactivate Linux Sleep/freeze/hibernate state without systemctl

Tags: linux, kernel, sleep

I have a system with a very specific Linux compilation that runs on ARM CPUs. It lacks almost all services (systemctl included) and generally-included software (apt-get, snap, etc.) and it is not connected to the web, so I cannot download anything (I can although send files through scp). The system can be accessed through ssh which is managed by dropbear (or alternatively I can access the system through UART). I work on the system by doing ssh.

The problem is that every morning I cannot access it in any way, even though every led is blinking green. It is like the system went into freeze/hibernation/sleep/dunno and all I/Os are deactivated. If I restart the system, everything starts working again.

Is there a way I can wake up the system or not make it go to sleep? I need something I can do through vim, like edit some configuration files, etc. (I have root access).

Thanks to everyone,
Please Help

Eventine

Comment: Does your "compilation" have a name and version?  What is the hardware it is running on?

Comment: The Kernel version is 4.19.0. The linux version is something based on this (https://github.com/pulp-platform/hero) but it is different. I cannot give you more information because I don't have them and cannot retreive them. The hardware is a Zynq Ultrascale+ zcu102, aka a quad-core ARM® Cortex-A53 (+ other stuff like dual-core Cortex-R5 real-time processors, and a Mali-400 MP2 graphics processing unit)

Comment: Impressive.  Is the OS stored on SD card?

Comment: You could first gather some info on what is happening. Use `last -n20` and check the logs in `/var/log/syslog` for sleep, hibernation, shutdown or crashes. Once you identified what is happening, you may start stopping it.

Comment: Yesm the OS is stored on an SD card. 
`last -n20` gives not much result (aka only infomation till last reboot atm) since I think that some data are not permanent (i.e. the files on the home remains, but after each reboot we need to recopy all the libraries and apply all the configurations, I think it is due to some configuration during kernel compilation).
`/var/log/syslog` does not exist.

Comment: Do you ever remove the SD?  I have a similar problem when a Raspberry Pi has been running for a couple of years without the card ever being removed, and the Pi rebooting every night.  Removing the card, putting it back and it's good to go for another year.  Eventually, the card dies.

Comment: I recently removed the SD and reinserted it, so I don't think that's the issue, but I'll give it a try today and see if that helps.

Comment: The SD thing did not help. Still had the issue and still cannot figure it out. It really looks like sleep state because it becomes unreachable after about 30 min of idling